# how to get value from Set<>

Tags: java

```
 /**
     * @return Returns the parameters.
     */
    public Set<FeatureParameterDTO> getParameters() {
        return this.parameters;
    }
```

how can i get value from `getParameters`? `toString` is not ok? What is correct way?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393398/how-do-i-iterate-and-modify-java-sets

Comment: You can see this topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047957/best-way-to-get-value-from-collection-by-index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You possibly have multiple values. So you'd have to iterate over them. You should be more precise with your questions. This one is quite vage. Just a quick example:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class SetTest {

Set<Integer> parameters = new TreeSet<Integer>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SetTest st = new SetTest();
      Set<Integer> param = st.getParameters();
      param.add(1);
      param.add(2);
      param.add(3);

      for (Integer myVal : param) {
        System.out.println(myVal);
      }
   }

   public Set<Integer> getParameters() {
      return this.parameters;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the return value of `getParameters()`, like this:

```
for (FeatureParameterDTO fpt : getParameters()) {
  // do what you want with fpt
}
```