# Why a super class object couldn't handle a child class list

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism

I have an abstract super class called `Recipient` and two child classes `OfficialRecipient` and `PersonnelRecipient`. `OfficialRecipient` has a child class `OfficeFriendRecipient`. I also have defined class `InputOutput` which has a method `UpdateFile`. Here `Recipient` class has methods `getName ()`, `getEmail ()`, and `OfficialRecipient` has method `getDesignation ()`.

I have an array list defined as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

List <OfficialRecipient> official = new ArrayList<>();
```

When I try to write the following code, java is showing error. The error is rectified when I cast pointer to `OfficialRecipient`.

```
Iterator <Recipient> pointer = official.iterator();
while (pointer.hasNext()) InputOutput.UpdateFile("official", pointer.getName (), "null", pointer.getEmail (), pointer.getDesignation (), "null", filePath);
```

My question is why a superclass pointer could not handle a subclass `official` list. Isn't it what polymorphism supposed to do?
I've just started studying java and couldn't understand this concept. Please briefly explain.

The code compiles correct when writing like this:

```
Iterator <OfficialRecipient> pointer = official.iterator();
while (pointer.hasNext()) InputOutput.UpdateFile("official", ((Recipient) pointer).getName (), "null", ((Recipient) pointer).getEmail (), ((OfficialRecipient) pointer).getDesignation (), "null", filePath);
```

Comment: You're asking about an error thrown by some code, but we don't know what the error is, and we don't know what the code is either. Post the relevant code, and the exact and complete error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show is not valid. If `pointer` is an `Iterator` instance, then you cannot access the methods of `Recipient` using `pointer`. You need first to get the next element by calling `Recipient recipient = pointer.next()`. Then you are able to call the methods of `Recipient` using the variable `recipient` - not `pointer`.

`recipient.getDescription()` would not work because `getDescription()` is not declared at the class `Recipient`. But if you get the next element from the second `Iterator<OfficialRecipient>` like `OfficialRecipient recipient = pointer.next()` then `recipient` is of type `OfficialRecipient` where `getDescription()` is defined. Thus you can call `recipient.getDescription()`. The cast is then not necessary.

Summarizing:

- An `Iterator<T>` will provide you the next element of `T` but is not an instance of `T`. @see: [How do I iterate and modify Java Sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393398/how-do-i-iterate-and-modify-java-sets)
- Second point is the question linked above for which this question is already marked as duplicate.