# Can I add a new object to a collection while streaming it?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Set<Client>` which I am filling with results from a database query. The resulting rows contain different values for clients so that several rows contain values to be added to a single instance of `Client`.
The `Client`s are stored in the mentioned `Set<Client>` and currently, I am checking if the client is already present in that `Set` or needs to be created by the following stream:

```
Set<Client> clients = new TreeSet<>(); 
// yes, Client implements Comparable<Client>, has hashCode() and equals()

// some things that are irrelevant to this question happen here

// then iterating the database result
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
    int clientNumber = rs.getInt(...);
    String clientName = rs.getString(...);
    // get the client from the collection or create a new one if it isn't there
    Client client = clients.stream()
            .filter(c -> c.getNumber() == clientNumber)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(new Client(clientNumber, clientName));

    // here I have to check again if the client is in the Set, how can I avoid that?
}
```

However, this does — of course — not add a possibly newly created `Client` to the `Set<Client>`, I need to check again if `clients` contains this instance afterwards in order to find out if I have to add this instance to `clients` or not. I couldn't even try anthing because I couldn't even add methods of `Stream`, like `concat(...)` at any position in the `clients.stream()...` statement.

That leads to the following question:

Is there any way at all that provides a possibility of directly adding a new instance of `Client` (or any object) to the `Set` while streaming this `Set` and the new instance is created by `.orElse(new ...)`?

I can imagine something like `orElseAdd(new ...)` but couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: I assume `Client.equals` compares only `clientNumber`? In that case you don't need the stream at all, just `add` new clients into the set. The set will figure out whether it already exists or not.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, why would you need to check if `new Client(clientNumber, clientName)` is in the set ? You already filtered it with `clientNumber`. In addition, you're using a set and have implemented the right methods, why do you verify the presence before adding a new element ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel The problem is the `orElse(new Client(clientNumber, clientName);` that will create a new instance if there is no matching instance found in the set, but it doesn't add it to the set afterwards.

Comment: Because `Stream` are not meant for this kind of operations. And you are really duplicating the behavior of a `Set`, simply write `set.add()`

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel Thanks, it is definitely an ok idea to just add the resulting `Client` to the `Set`.

Comment: But remove also the `Stream`, I think that you're misusing the `Set`. This is the first line of its javadoc `A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the process of creating a client is light enough to not worry about creating a dup, you can just let Set control it for you.

```
Set<Client> clients = new TreeSet<>(); 
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
    int clientNumber = rs.getInt(...);
    String clientName = rs.getString(...);
    clients.add(new Client(clientNumber, clientName))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A `Map` provides a useful method of inserting something if it doesn't exist.

It also doesn't hurt to store clients in a map. It seems from your example that `clientNumber` is unique so that will be the key.

```
Map<Integer, Client> clients = new TreeMap<>();

...

Client client = clients.computeIfAbsent(clientNumber, key -> new Client(clientNumber, clientName));
```

When the lambda is executed, `key` is equal to `clientNumber`, so it can be ignored. Note here that the lambda is *only* executed when the client is not in the map, so don't fear about creting too many objects. Not that it matters since it's also creating boxed `Integer` objects if `clientNumber` is larger than the caching threshold (255 in my VM). Luckily Java is very efficient when dealing with short-lived objects.

Comment: Thanks, I have already thought about using a `Map<Integer, Client>`. And just out of interest: Why does a `Set` have no `computeIfAbsent`? Is that relying on a key?

Comment: Yes. If you query the presence of an object in a `Set` you do it by-value, so you already have an object. There's no point in having a lambda that creates a new object.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way at all that provides a possibility of directly adding a new instance ... to the Set?

See this now:

> For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general, the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances. Some Iterator implementations (including those of all the general purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to throw this exception if this behavior is detected. Iterators that do this are known as fail-fast iterators, as they fail quickly and cleanly, rather that risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.
>
> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

Quoting from [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

Thing is: **adding** to a Set while iterating it is simply not a good idea. Most likely, an instance of the above exception would be thrown at you. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393398/how-do-i-iterate-and-modify-java-sets) for some more thoughts.

Also, note, conceptually: would you want a freshly added object to show up in that stream, too? What if your Set is sorted, and the new object goes somewhere in the set ... that was "already" streamed?!

Long story short: what you intend to do is bad practice. Rather collect all **new** Client objects in a separate set, and process that one by itself later on.

And note: it isn't mandatory, but the whole "streaming" API suggests you to follow *functional programming* paradigms. In functional programming, you don't *modify* things, you rather create new things. So, as said: collect new objects in a new set, and then finally, create a new merged set that contains old and new objects.

Comment: Thanks, I know about the concurrent modification problem, but I thought there might be some method that, instead of returning a new `Client` at the end of the stream, just adds a new one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really wants to use `TreeSet` to maintain the sorting order of `clients` and wants to add the non existing client to `clients` collection set then try the following

#### Step 1

Since `TreeSet` maintains the sorted order, the `Client` object need to implement **java.lang.Comparable's compareTo()** method like the following:

```
public class Client implements Comparable<Client>{

    private int clientNumber;
    private String clientName;

    public Client(int clientNumber, String clientName) {
        this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Client client) {
        return clientNumber - client.getClientNumber();
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

#### Step 2

Since Set handles the duplicates internally just use

```
while (rs.next()) {
    int clientNumber = rs.getInt(...);
    String clientName = rs.getString(...);
    clients.add(new Client(clientNumber, clientName));
}
```

#### Step 3

For List collection Stream, Filter and add the non existing client to our `clients` collection set  using the following way

```
while (rs.next()) {
    int clientNumber = rs.getInt(...);
    String clientName = rs.getString(...);
    clients.addAll(Lists.newArrayList(new Client(clientNumber, clientName)).stream()
            .filter(client -> !clients.contains(client))
            .collect(toList()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about **Step 1** and have implemented `compareTo(Client other)` (a bit differently, but with the same functionality). I will check out **Step 2**.

Comment: I could, but I can just tell you: I check if `this.number == other.getNumber()` and `return 0` if yes, otherwise I check if `this.number > other.getNumber()` and then `return 1` and `else return -1;` but I think that does not really matter if I have `equals()` and `hashCode()` as well.

Comment: It looks fine for me....but what issue that causes you when simply use `clients.add(new Client(clientNumber, clientName));`

Comment: There is no real issue with that (as I realized after some answers and comments were given here). I was checking if I got a `Client` that was in the `Set` before or a new one, but that is just not necessary if I use a `TreeSet`.